# Kryo setWarnUnregisteredClasses to true showing nothing in spark config

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("example")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    .set("setWarnUnregisteredClasses","true")
```

When `registrationRequired` is set to true, it throws exception for `class Person is not registered and also "org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol$TaskCommitMessage" is not registered`

So, now in default it is false, so making `setWarnUnregisteredClasses` to true, it should show warning message for unregistered class encountered as provided in the documentation https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#serializer-framework? But, nothing is shown in the logs regarding serialization.

What I am trying to do is to get a list of all unregistered class into my logs by setting this property `.set("setWarnUnregisteredClasses","true")`

`Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/12/10 15:56:09 WARN Utils: Your hostname, knoldus-Vostro-3546 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.113 instead (on interface enp7s0)
19/12/10 15:56:09 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/12/10 15:56:10 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.4
19/12/10 15:56:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/12/10 15:56:12 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: kyroExample
19/12/10 15:56:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: knoldus
19/12/10 15:56:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: knoldus
19/12/10 15:56:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/12/10 15:56:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/12/10 15:56:14 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(knoldus); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(knoldus); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/12/10 15:56:17 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 36235.
19/12/10 15:56:17 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/12/10 15:56:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/12/10 15:56:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
19/12/10 15:56:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
19/12/10 15:56:18 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-956a186e-cfbd-4ad2-b531-9f46bff96984
19/12/10 15:56:18 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 870.9 MB
19/12/10 15:56:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.1.113:4040
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41737.
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.113:41737
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.113, 41737, None)
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.113:41737 with 870.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.113, 41737, None)
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.113, 41737, None)
19/12/10 15:56:19 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.113, 41737, None)
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at KyroExample.scala:28
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (take at KyroExample.scala:28) with 1 output partitions
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (take at KyroExample.scala:28)
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at filter at KyroExample.scala:24), which has no missing parents
19/12/10 15:56:21 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.0 KB, free 870.9 MB)
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1730.0 B, free 870.9 MB)
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.113:41737 (size: 1730.0 B, free: 870.9 MB)
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1161
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at filter at KyroExample.scala:24) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
19/12/10 15:56:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (243 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 249045 bytes)
19/12/10 15:56:22 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 293.3 KB, free 870.6 MB)
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_0 in memory on 192.168.1.113:41737 (size: 293.3 KB, free: 870.6 MB)
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 0:
[rdd_1_0]
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1132 bytes result sent to driver
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 924 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (take at KyroExample.scala:28) finished in 1.733 s
19/12/10 15:56:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: take at KyroExample.scala:28, took 1.895530 s`

There is no unregistered class encountered logs. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
The issue is that `setWarnUnregisteredClasses` is a Kryo configuration that currently (I actually use Spark 2.4.4) is not exposed through Spark.
You have to set the specific configuration in Kryo.
The workaround I used was to have a custom `KryoRegistrator`.
Then I used it in this way:

```
class MyKryoRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {

  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo): Unit = {
    kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false)
    kryo.setWarnUnregisteredClasses(true)
...
```

Comment: Yes this works @Thomas Kaliakos, but how to get those logs by setting in the spark config itself as `setWarnUnregisteredClasses,true`

Comment: yes this is the point...as far as I can tell at least, there is no Spark configuration for that.

Comment: Is that setting `kryo.setWarnUnregisteredClasses(true)` not there in spark 2.11.2, as this method is not appearing after `kryo.` @ Thomas Kaliakos

Comment: I am not sure which spark version you are referring to. My setup is Spark 2.4.4 and Scala 2.11.12

Comment: actually spark 2.1 @Thomas Kaliakos

Comment: he above method worked for me as wll, but Mr. minilog by default prints on stdout and my usual log4j for spark config used to setup the logger on stderr. So, if it happens to others not to find such logs, give a look to driver/executors stdout log files! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using kryo registration so custom and other classes need to be registered with kryo and also both classes should implement serialize interface.

setWarnUnregisteredClasses will give warnings and conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true") throws exception for classes not registered.

You have to register person and TaskCommitMessage like

```
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Person]))
```

Comment: Yes, that's my point, setting `conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")` will result in throwing exception if I dont register. And setting `conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "false")` does not throws exception, btt it should show a message for unregistered class encountered, right as I have set this property `setWarnUnregisteredClasses` to true? @tarun

Comment: @phineas It does show,can you share the log for that ?

Comment: settings `.set("setWarnUnregisteredClasses","true")` and `conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "false")`, so unregistered class encountered logs must pop up according to the documentation right?